# returns doesn't wait for the cycle to end

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, return

I've a problem with my code (typescript):

```js
async getAllServers(@Res() response) {
        const servers = await this.serverService.getAllServers();
        let bot = []
        
        servers.map(async server => {
            console.log(server.id)

            bot.push(await this.serverService.getInfo(server.id));

            console.log(bot)
        })
        
        return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
            bot, 
            servers
        })
    }
```

This function need to return 2 array, but the second array (bot) is always empty. 
This is because return is executed before the loop. 
How I can execute the return when the loop finish?

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

Comment: You’re kind of misusing `map` because you’re ignoring the return value. But you need the return value in order to await the Promises returned by the async function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `map` function has an `async` function which will push the functions to the `microtask queue` and will execute when the `call stack` is empty.

To be able to return the `bot` array you need to wait for these async functions to complete.

```
async getAllServers(@Res() response) {
        const servers = await this.serverService.getAllServers();
        let bot = []
        let botServerCalls = [];
        // get the API call Promise in an array to be able to hit them parallely 
        botServerCalls = servers.map(server => {
            console.log(server.id)
            // assuming this returns a Promise to make API call
            return this.serverService.getInfo(server.id);
        });

        // use Promise.all to make API calls in parallel and wait for Promise.all to resolve
        bot = await Promise.all(botServerCalls);
        
        return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
            bot, 
            servers
        })
    }
```